# change the class of a link with xslt

Tags: xslt

I would like to change the class of a link but something must be wrong, however I can't see where.
I have checked that the if test is OK.

Could you tell me where I was wrong ?

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="title-link-proced">
<a target="BodyPart" class="little_link">
   <xsl:if test="@change = 'true'">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">little_link_evolution</xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:if>
</a>
</xsl>
```

I also tried

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="title-link-proced">
<a target="BodyPart" class="little_link">
   <xsl:if test="@change = 'true'">
    <xsl:attribute name="class" select="little_link_evolution"></xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:if>
</a>
</xsl>
```

but that dit not work either

EDIT:
I checked that there is a change attribute with the value true (if I display:

```
    <xsl:value-of select="@change"/>
```

I get true)

EDIT 2

XML iput

```
<level_4 change="true"  module="2X3E-ZE_RTY_OAD" title="presentation">           
</level_4>
```

Comment: What does the input XML look like?  Are you sure that the current context node from the input is an element and that this element has a `change` attribute with the value `true`?

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure the test is correct, I do not think the problem is XML since the value is OK, it is more how to modify the class

Comment: What is your *input*? You showed only a fragment of a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it might help some one day

rather than attemting to modify the existing class, I decide not to attribute a class in the beginning and to do this:

```
<a target="BodyPart">

 <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="@change = 'true'">
    <xsl:attribute name="class">little_link_evolution</xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:when>  
   <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:attribute name="class">little_link</xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

And it worked !